# Java - Fastest way to fill a rectangle

Tags: java, optimization, graphics

I prefer to use my own methods for drawing things in Java. I use these two methods to fill a rectangle:

```
public static void drawPixel(Vector2 position) { 
    g.drawLine((int) position.getX(), (int) position.getY(), (int) position.getX(), (int) position.getY()); 
}
public static void fill(Rectangle area) {
    for (int x = (int) area.getTopLeft().getX(); x <= (int) area.getBottomRight().getX(); x++) {
        for (int y = (int) area.getTopLeft().getY(); y <= (int) area.getBottomRight().getY(); y++) {
            drawPixel(new Vector2(x, y));
        }
    }
}
```

When I use this fill method to fill the window every frame to draw the background it becomes horribly slow. What can I do to optimize this?

I also use my own line drawing method in order to avoid a bug on my computer that does not draw lines accurately.
Custom line method:

```
public static void drawLine(Line line) {
    double x2 = line.getEnd().getX(), x1 = line.getStart().getX(), y2 = line.getEnd().getY(), y1 = line.getStart().getY();
    // delta of exact value and rounded value of the dependent variable
    int d = 0;
    int dy = (int) Math.abs(y2 - y1);
    int dx = (int) Math.abs(x2 - x1);
    int dy2 = (dy << 1); // slope scaling factors to avoid floating
    int dx2 = (dx << 1); // point
    int ix = x1 < x2 ? 1 : -1; // increment direction
    int iy = y1 < y2 ? 1 : -1;
    if (dy <= dx) {
        for (;;) {
            drawPixel(new Vector2(x1, y1));
            if (x1 == x2)
                break;
            x1 += ix;
            d += dy2;
            if (d > dx) {
                y1 += iy;
                d -= dx2;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (;;) {
           drawPixel(new Vector2(x1, y1));
            if (y1 == y2)
                break;
            y1 += iy;
            d += dx2;
            if (d > dy) {
                x1 += ix;
                d -= dy2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not answer your question. And sorry, you don't want to hear this. But I have to say it: Drawing stuff like that is like mowing a lawn with nail scissors. Call `graphics.fillRect` and you're done. The method calls on `Graphics` internally delegate to native methods, with hardware support. No optimization whatsoever can cause the current code to *not* run horribly slow compared to that.

Comment: In `drawPixel`, you call `drawLine`. You also call `drawLine` in `drawPixel`, so it seems you got some recursion going on. I wouldn't doubt the lag is a result from trying to create your own drawing methods which have bad implementations. Stick with the draw methods available through `Graphics` if possible. @Marco13 Optimizations can remove the lag from his current implementation. It's just not worth working through, since the functionality is already in `Graphics`. I wouldn't go as far as to say "*if its not from the JDK, it wont run as fast*"

Comment: I use g.drawLine in drawPixel because it draws one-pixel lines accurately, but not longer ones. I use my drawLine in fill because it draws accurately

Answer (score 1):

Using `drawLine` to draw a single pixel doesn't seem to be a good idea. Why not just use `drawLine` directly to draw lines and hence, remove the inner loop?

I don't know a single bit about JAVA, but it occured to me that calling a method from inside the loop test condition, only to check if the index variable has reached the final value, seems like a big overhead to me. I rather use a variable to cache the relevant value, which won't vary, and use it in the test condition.

```
public static void fill(Rectangle area) {
    int y1 = (int) area.getTopLeft().getY();
    int y2 = (int) area.getBottomRight().getY();
    int x2 = (int) area.getBottomRight().getX();
    for (int x = (int) area.getTopLeft().getX(); x <= x2; x++) {
        g.drawLine (x, y1, x, y2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed my code so now it draws lines from left to right across the area, but it still is just as slow. I have my own line drawing method because on my computer java has a bug where it draws lines one pixel too long, and my method works. Could this be the reason it lags? (post edited)

Comment: @MCMastery I wouldn't call it a bug until you confirmed it's a bug. Try posting a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem and someone might be able to assist you with what you think might be a bug

Comment: I have seen the bug on the java bug tracker

Comment: Of course it's just as slow. Your drawLine method is painfully slow. I thought drawLine was a native method.

Comment: `drawLine` is a general line drawing function. In low-level libraries, I always include a fast `drawHorizontalLine` as well, especially for this purpose. Unfortunately, it seems Graphics does not expose it. (And creating your own using `drawPixel` is counterproductive...)